# Adding JQuery icon sets to LaTeX documents

Tags: packages, python, sphinx, icon

I have found multiple references to adding TeX to JQuery-enabled things, and a simple search found plug-ins for inserting LaTeX equation builders into JQuery but I don't think I've seen questions in the opposite direction.

I'm building documentation in Python-Sphinx for a WebUI, and it's no problem getting the icons that the WebUI uses to show up in the .html output (obviously the WebUI uses the JQuery icon set, and Python can also display the same icons). When I output to LaTeX though, the icons simply don't render. Luckily there isn't some kind of broken image/broken link placeholder in the outputs, so I've been kind of ignoring it for now.

As with most Python-to-TeX outputs, I snip the preamble and paste in a pre-written header that I keep on a notepad. Is there a package that allows you to load in JQuery icons into a LaTeX document that I can use, but can't find? Or would I need to create a new command for each icon that gets included in that re-used header?

Comment: What kind of files are the icons in?  Does a file have multiple icons, and they usually get clipped away so that you only see the one you want?

Comment: I doubt JQuery is using TeX. It is probably using MathJaX or MathML or something like that, which is unrelated to TeX. You can include images easily in LaTeX, but I've no idea what JQuery icons are.